# Getting error on a switch script - Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' line: 8 file: Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that moves rows from 1 main sheet to different destination sheets within my spreadsheet.

I got recommended to use switch that I think makes sense but I'm getting this error because of the brackets.

I have looked it through and I can't see why I get this error.

Here is the code down below

```js
function allInOne(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var sheet = range.sheet;
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (e.value != "") {
    if (sheetName == "Pipe") {
      switch (r.getColumn() {
        case 7:
          
          var row = r.getRow();
          var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Återkomster");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

        // 
      // do column 7 tasks
      break;

        case 8:
       
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

      // 
      // do column 8 tasks
      break;

        case 13:
       
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bokad");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target).range.clearContent();

      // 
      // do column 13 tasks
      break;

        default:
      // do nothing because the edit is happening on a column we don't want to watch
      return;
    
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis in the switch statement. It should read:

```
switch (r.getColumn()) {
```